# How to get a list of search terms that returns no match from elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want stats about terms users are searching for on my Elasticsearch instance that returns no results.

Is that info available in Elasticsearch or is it something I have to track manually?

For example,

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "FieldName",
      "analyzer": "standard",
      "query": "TermThatReturnsNoRecords"
    }
  }
}
```

The above query will return no match, so I want to be able to know that the term `TermThatReturnsNoRecords` was used X amount of time and returned no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no out-of-the-box feature that does that in elasticsearch, but you need to resort on elasticsearch logs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/logging.html

logs include the number of query results, which you can use to get the information you're looking for

example:

```
{
  "type": "index_search_slowlog",
  "timestamp": "2030-08-30T11:59:37,786+02:00",
  "level": "WARN",
  "component": "i.s.s.query",
  "cluster.name": "distribution_run",
  "node.name": "node-0",
  "message": "[index6][0]",
  "took": "78.4micros",
  "took_millis": "0",
  "total_hits": "0 hits", <--- you can filter by this value
  "stats": "[]",
  "search_type": "QUERY_THEN_FETCH",
  "total_shards": "1",
  "source": "{\"query\":{\"match_all\":{\"boost\":1.0}}}", <--- your query
  "id": "MY_USER_ID",
  "cluster.uuid": "Aq-c-PAeQiK3tfBYtig9Bw",
  "node.id": "D7fUYfnfTLa2D7y-xw6tZg"
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to log that info into a searchable index from the API?

Comment: not that i'm aware of https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html